# How to Create Custom SplashScreen on Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, splash-screen

I want show custom splash screen with animation. I tried add LottieSplashScreen plugin but i can't do this. 
Tried with this code

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-lottie-splashscreen
```

But i facing

```
'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-lottie-splashscreen': Error: Hook failed with error code ENOENT: C:\Users\bbara\Desktop\GuvercinSepetim\plugins\cordova-plugin-lottie-splashscreen\hooks\ios\update_pod_repo.sh
    at C:\Users\bbara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:224:23
    at _rejected (C:\Users\bbara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:864:24)
    at C:\Users\bbara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:890:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\bbara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:1142:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\bbara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:808:41)
    at C:\Users\bbara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (C:\Users\bbara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\bbara\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:9)
Hook failed with error code ENOENT: C:\Users\bbara\Desktop\GuvercinSepetim\plugins\cordova-plugin-lottie-splashscreen\hooks\ios\update_pod_repo.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running a cordova node but not ionic cordova:
    cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-lottie-splashscreen

According to ionic documentation:

```
npm install @ionic-native/lottie-splash-screen
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-lottie-splashscreen
```

And here is the referance:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/lottie-splash-screen

And here is the github reposatory of the plugin :

https://github.com/timbru31/cordova-plugin-lottie-splashscreen

Comment: there was missing code , i wrote like ionic cordova plugin add .... But i facing error when run code. I used this references. Can u try or another idea?

Comment: https://medium.com/@prashantg9912/how-to-add-beautiful-lottie-splashsceen-to-ionic-app-7fdbc00f6cea

Comment: I tried this but after applied this steps can't build.

Comment: Look ,download this and test on it,if it works then recheck your main project ,else then we try another solutions.

Comment: Ok i searched much for you but didn't find a well solution, after 6 hours i'll be on my computer and i'll create a project and iam sure i'll give you the answer you need here.hope you could wait and check back.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, if you answer after 6 hours i'll see and answer tomorrow.

Comment: I could add the plugin but now facing " Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForRelease'.
 " ERROR

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746608/react-native-android-execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithmul/53746935

Comment: See this post its in react native but it is the same as ionic structure so try it.

Comment: Can i connect to you another platform?

Comment: I facing the ' Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "fs" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.' ERROR

Comment: 0096176303389 this is my whatsapp number.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into Capacitor instead of Cordova. You can still use all your Cordova libraries, but the Capacitor build is a bit cleaner. I followed this tutorial and found it very useful with good tools. It worked for me first time, which is never the case with some Ionic stuff!

https://enappd.com/blog/icon-splash-in-ionic-react-capacitor-apps/114/

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are describing was fixed in the v0.8.1 release. It originated from preparing/building the iOS platform on a Windows machine - which won't work anyways. Because cordova-ios supports recent Pod installations out of the box, it's no longer required to sync the repo, i.e, the hook is obsolete. However, the lottie plugin won't fail anymore.

Side note: I'm the author of this plugin.